# Finding depth of a Python tree from a text file

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, and I was trying out some questions when I encountered this problem. A tree is defined in a text file in the following manner,

```
d:
e:
b: d e
c:
a: b c
```

So, I want to write a simple python script that finds the depth of this. I'm not able to figure out a strategy to work this out. Is there any algorithm or technique for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be as follows:

1. Find elements with no children.
2. For each of these, find the parent. Determine if any elements have this parent as a child - if not, your length is two (2).
3. If so, find the parent of the parent. Repeat step 2, incrementing your length counter. Continue the process updating a counter with each step.

For your case:

```
d -> b -> a (len 3)
e -> b -> a (len 3)
c -> a (len 2)
```

This could be described as a 'bottom up' tree construction method/algorithm.

Comment: I think I understand this strategy. I'l try it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The tree format you've given has a nice property: if `x` is the child of `y`, then `x` is given before `y` in the file. So you can simply loop through the file once and read the depth into a dictionary. For example:

```
depth = {}
for line in f:
    parent, children = read_node(line)
    if children:
        depth[parent] = max(depth.get(child,1) for child in children) + 1
```

Then just `print depth['a']`, as `a` is the root. Here `read_node` is a quick function to parse the parent and children from a line of the file:

```
def read_node(line):
    parent, children = line.split(":")
    return parent, children.split()
```

Comment: I did something similar to this, although I didn't use the property you mentioned above, so I iterated the outer loop till I ran out of "child only" lines

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by depth, if it's how many steps you have to go to visit every node, you could use the [Depth-First Search](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) to see how long it takes to visit every node in the graph.

Here's a simple implementation:

```
text_tree = """d:
e:
b: d e
c:
a: b c"""

tree = {}

for line in text_tree.splitlines():
    node, childs = line.split(":")
    tree[node] = set(childs.split())

def dfs(graph, start):
    visited, stack = [], [start]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.append(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex])
    return visited

result = dfs(tree,"a")    
print "It took %d steps, to visit every node in tree, the path took was %s"%(len(result),result)
```

Which outputs:

```
It took 5 steps, to visit every node in tree, the path took was ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c']
```